# Pandas int type to date type

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

i am new to pandas and I try to convert an int type-column to an date type-column .

The int in the df is something like: 10712 (first day, then month, then year).

I tried solving this with:

```
df_date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d%m%Y')
```

but I always get the following value error:

`time data '10712' does not match format '%d%m%Y' (match)`

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Do you expect `10712` to be `10-07-2012` ?

Comment: No, 01-07-2012.

Comment: Then the accepted answer is incorrect.

Comment: @txmai, you changed your request right to opposite. Your 1st comment was *"Yes, exactly"*

Comment: yes I'm sorry been coding for too long and I didn't read your comment correct the first time

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Oh, now I see. I've revoked my downvote.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins, Oh, I wouldn't post it if I knew the final requirement at that time. Anyway ... just a bit awkward case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `%y` (2-digit year) instead of `%Y` (4-digit year). But that is not enough.

The format `%d%m%y` converts `10712` to `10-07-2012`, not to `1-07-2012` as you expect.

That's because of the following feature of the underlying `strptime`:

> When used with the strptime() method, the leading zero is optional for
> %m

A workaround could be to convert to a format properly understandable by `strptime` (and `to_datetime`):

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [10712, 20813, 30914]})
>>> df 
    date
0  10712
1  20813
2  30914

>>> df1 = df.date.astype(str).str.replace('(\d+)(\d\d)(\d\d)',
                                         r'\2/\1/\3', regex=True)
>>> df1
0    07/1/12
1    08/2/13
2    09/3/14

>>> pd.to_datetime(df1)
0   2012-07-01
1   2013-08-02
2   2014-09-03
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `%y` year specifier to parse year without century digits:

```
In [654]: pd.to_datetime(10712, format='%d%m%y')
Out[654]: Timestamp('2012-07-10 00:00:00')
```